# decompose() for yearly time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to perform analysis on a time series data of inflation rates from the year 1960 to 2015. The dataset is a yearly time series over 56 years with 1 real value per each year, which is the following:

```
Year    Inflation percentage
1960    1.783264746
1961    1.752021563
1962    3.57615894
1963    2.941176471
1964    13.35403727
1965    9.479452055
1966    10.81081081
1967    13.0532972
1968    2.996404315
1969    0.574712644
1970    5.095238095
1971    3.081105573
1972    6.461538462
1973    16.92815855
1974    28.60169492
1975    5.738605162
1976    -7.63438068
1977    8.321619342
1978    2.517518817
1979    6.253164557
1980    11.3652609
1981    13.11510484
1982    7.887270664
1983    11.86886396
1984    8.32157969
1985    5.555555556
1986    8.730811404
1987    8.798689021
1988    9.384775808
1989    3.26256011
1990    8.971233545
1991    13.87024609
1992    11.78781925
1993    6.362038664
1994    10.21150033
1995    10.22488756
1996    8.977149075
1997    7.16425362
1998    13.2308409
1999    4.669821024
2000    4.009433962
2001    3.684807256
2002    4.392199745
2003    3.805865922
2004    3.76723848
2005    4.246353323
2006    6.145522388
2007    6.369996746
2008    8.351816444
2009    10.87739112
2010    11.99229692
2011    8.857845297
2012    9.312445605
2013    10.90764331
2014    6.353194544
2015    5.872426595
```

'stock1' contains my data where the first column stands for Year, and the second for 'Inflation.percentage', as follows:

`stock1<-read.csv("India-Inflation time series.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, as.is=TRUE)`

The following is my code for creating the time series object:

```
stock <- ts(stock1$Inflation.percentage,start=(1960), end=(2015),frequency=1)
```

Following this, I am trying to decompose the time series object 'stock' using the following line of code:

```
decom_add <- (decompose(stock, type ="additive"))
```

Here I get an error:

> Error in decompose(stock, type = "additive") :    time series has no
>   or less than 2 periods

Why is this so? I initially thought it has something to do with frequency, but since the data is annual, the frequency has to be 1 right? If it is 1, then aren't there definitely more than 2 periods in the data?

Why isn't `decompose()` working? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please show a reproducible example.

Comment: I've not much experience with time series, but `decompose` decomposes a time series into seasonal, trend and irregular components. With a frequency of 1, you got no seasonal cycle. So you can't use it this way, but maybe just get the trend and its errors.

Comment: The problem is with frequency. The function does a breakdown for each season. You have one season.

Comment: But, can't seasonality be yearly as well? There can be recurring patterns, say, at the end of each decade right? How do I capture that, given that I just have one entry each year? I have added the data to the question as well.

Comment: For example `decompose(ts(stock1$Inflation.percentage,start=c(6, 1), end=c(11, 6), frequency=10))`?

Comment: The function is not attempting to 'find' the season length for you. You have to supply it. If you want ten years then use 10 as your frequency.

Comment: Right. It was an issue with the way I understood the concept. How silly! Thanks a lot for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Please try for `frequency=2`, because frequency needs to be greater than 1. Because this action will change your model, for me the better way is to load data which contain and month column, so the frequency will be 12.